# How to initiate a specific method when developing a eclipse plug-in

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I want to write an eclipse plug-in that can show me all the callers of a specific method - the constructor of the class `Thread`. I have found the article "[Java: Find all callers of a method – get all methods that call a particular method](http://www.programcreek.com/2011/07/find-all-callers-of-a-method/)". But I still need to initiate an `IMethod` object to be the input for the `getCallersOf` method. It seems `IMethod` is an interface. I have no idea how to new an `IMethod` object to represent the constructor of the class `Thread`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by looking at the org.eclipse.jdt.core IJavaProject interface.  You get instances of this class using the JavaCore class.  These instances have indirect references to the IMethod instances you're looking for.  An IProject is an IJavaProject and it has types in its classpathfragments and those types have methods...

For your tool to really be usable, you'll need a way to choose the method you want to report on.  For that I suggest you create a new Eclipse plugin project using the popup menu template.  That will get you a menu item in the Package Explorer's context menu that can invoke your tool's logic on a method you've selected.